# Setting initial & max JVM memory in an Azure Function (App Service)?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

In the following context

- Azure Function under App Service Plan
- P2V3 instance
- Java 11 worker

Does it make sense to set `JAVA_OPTS` to `-Xms14848m -Xmx14848m`, as described on [Configure a Java app for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-java?pivots=platform-linux#customization-and-tuning)?

By default, `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` is set to 1. If this setting is left unchanged, then there should be only one worker per instance. Thus it should be safe to set the initial memory like that. Are there any problems with this reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it make sense to set `JAVA_OPTS` to `-Xms14848m -Xmx14848m`

Yes, it is used to allocate the memory while the iteration starts.  To set the **allocated memory** or **JVM Runtime options**, it will pass the `JAVA_OPTS` with the Options and values to the app service.

When App Service starts, it passes this setting (**`JAVA_OPTS`**)to the Java runtime as an environment variable.

> By default, `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` is set to 1. If this setting is left unchanged, then there should be only one worker per instance. Thus it should be safe to set the initial memory like that. Are there any problems with this reasoning?

Yes, It is safe. Even the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` is set to 1  the memory allocation of `JAVA_OPTS` can be passed to the Function Worker run time. When the iteration starts it will take the environment variable of `JAVA_OPTS` and its value and process with their memory allocation.  Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-java?pivots=platform-linux#set-java-runtime-options) for more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. For my understanding: if I were to change `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` to n > 1, is it also safe to do (assuming the same context)? Would both workers be running in the same JVM, or is there a risk of running out of memory with both worker having their own JVM?

Comment: yes it is safe. Every iteration it will allocate accordingly in azure.